# Java program doesn't read file contents if the file has the same name as the last one used

Tags: java, file

I'm writing a Java application to read in an xml file, parse the contents and output the contents to console. I discovered a problem during testing where I was using the same file but changing the contents. In this case, the output was the same as the previous run even though the contents of the file had changed between runs. Is there a way to force Java to read the file or clear a cache?

I tried removing the file from the file system before running, it still got the contents from somewhere.

```
File xmlFile = new File(this.filepath);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = getSafeDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("default");
this.myDefault = getDefaultFromNodeList(nList);
```

Comment: What you describe is not possible. Rethiink your observations.

Comment: @Marichyasana What?

Comment: Either you are only calling DocumentBuilder.parse once, or you are not reading the file you think you’re reading.  Print `xmlFile.getAbsolutePath()` and verify that you are in fact modifying/deleting that file.